# How to solder the stainless steel rods

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, material-science, brazing, soldering

How can we solder two stainless steel rods
material- Stainless steel 304 or SS316

OD-6mm
ID-1.6mm
Depth-4mm

Or there is any other better option to join these two parts?
[image: parts to be solder]

Comment: cut threads ....

Comment: If all that was machined yourself, you could have probably made that to be press fit.

Comment: the part will rotate at around 1000 rpm, so there might be chances to lose.

Answer (score 2):

solder generally will not work on stainless steel (it can't stick because of the oxide that forms on the surface of the steel). You can *weld* it instead, using welding wire or rod specifically compounded to work with stainless. If the join between the two parts is *threaded*, you can lock them together using a type of glue called *thread locker* which is effective yet allows the parts to be torqued apart at some later time if necessary.